# AttributeError: 'StandardScaler' object has no attribute 'var_'

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, data-science, attributeerror

I get this error message attempting to use the .var_ and .mean_ attribute of StandardScaler from Sci-Kit Learn. I saw in another SO post that it is no longer supported in newer versions so I downloaded an older one and it did not work either.

Answer (score 1):

From [offical documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.StandardScaler.html) the attributes `var_` and `mean_` are still available on the latest stable version (0.24.1 at the time of this post).

Nevertheless to access `var_` and `mean_` which respectively returns variance value and mean value the scaler needs to be fitted to your data. Otherwise these attributes won't be available. Also be sure that Scaler parameters `with_mean` and `with_std` are set to `True`.
e.g. :

```
data = [[0, 0], [0, 0], [1, 1], [1, 1]]
scaler = StandardScaler()
scaler.mean_ ---> AttributeError: 'StandardScaler' object has no attribute 'mean_'
scaler.fit(data)
scaler.mean_ ---> array([0.5, 0.5])
```